# Writing a big file with np.save in Python in a while True Loop

Tags: python, linux, numpy, cp

I am scraping a website with a while True loop, and then saving all of the data to a file with np.savez. I want to process the npz file, but the file updates faster than I can copy it. Here's my code:

```
while True:
  time.sleep(1.5)
  for post in new:
    all_posts.append(post)
  np.savez('records.npz', posts)
  new = other_site.get_next()
```

Initially to process the data I was scraping I just would copy the file, but now the file is too big and it gets corrupted every time. I could restart this process from the beginning and save less often so I would have more time to copy, but I'd like to know if there's a way I can recover the data I've written. Another idea I had was to truncate the end of the file such that it still looks like an npz file and python can read it, but I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: A `.npz` file is just a zipped file of `.npy` files, so you can process the files with any zip utility. Are you asking if there is a way to rescue the data you've created? I'm not quite clear where exactly your problem is.

Comment: If you're trying to recover the truncated file, try `zip -FF --out repaired_file.npz`. You may have lost some data, but might be able to recover most of it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your file getting trampled or over-written, why not write some python code to avoid this? For example, you could save to a new file for each site, and collect these files in a directory;

```
import os

os.mkdir('scraped_sites')

while True:
   time.sleep(1.5)
   for post in new:
      all_posts.append(post)

   # create a unique file path
   save_file = os.path.join('scraped_sites', 'records_%s.npz' % other_site)
   np.savez(save_file, all_posts)

   new = other_site.get_next()
```

This way your file will never be trampled and so you needn't worry about processing it before it gets written again. If you don't like the idea of naming your files, check out [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html)

Also, `while True` can be dangerous as your loop will never exit - I assume that you've just written this for brevity, but it would be good to have a `break` or `while <conditional` so that you don't accidentally force the loop to exit when it's mid file write.